# orangebox (lightbox) on page load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

im not to familiar with jquery or javascript so i have found solutions to similar problems but none explain how it works so i can convert it to use my version of a lightbox.

So i want orangebox (jquery plug-in) to load when a new page opens. its for notifying to users that they have successfully submitted a contact form.

here is the link to orangebox http://orangebox.davidpaulhamilton.net

something that could trigger this maybe

```
    <a href="#thankyou" rel="lightbox" title="ty">Thank You?</a>
<div id="inlineContent" style="display:none">Thank You</div>
</span></div>
</span></div>
<div id="thankyou" style="display:none"> 
    <p>Thank you for contacting us, we will reply soon.
</p> 
    </div>
```

thanks guys

Comment: The developer has included some basic documentation on how to get it up and running:  http://orangebox.davidpaulhamilton.net/docs.html.  Have you done any of this?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the Public Methods you can see how to create a new orangebox:
http://orangebox.davidpaulhamilton.net/api.html

```
$("anchorID").orangebox('create');
```

Add this code on the page you want to create the orangebox with the div id *thankyou*.

```
    $(function(){
      $("#thankyou").orangebox('create');
    });
```

This is not tested. Let me know if it works.

And just to let you know:

```
$(function() {
```

is equivalent to

```
$("document").ready(function(){
```

so the orangebox should be created when the document is loaded.